# How to update array in a multiple array keeping same key

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-push

I have an array below. What i need to do is unset one array inside "Urunler" than updating a new array. Very crucial one is how can push new array by keeping same key value which is same deleted one.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Urun] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 1384
                    [Urun_kodu] => UKy74GhoD1LZ
                    [Urun_adi] => Bizim Ayçiçek Yağı Teneke 5 Lt
                    [Urun_resim] => uploads/urunler_v/UKy74GhoD1LZ/637b4-bizim-aycicek-yagi-tenekelxwbmlgpdh.jpg
                    [Esas_tutar] => 27.00
                    [Esas_tutar_kdvsiz] => 25.00
                    [Kdv_tutar] => 2.00
                    [Kdv_tutar_adetli] => 6.00
                    [Adetli_tutar] => 81.00
                    [Adetli_tutar_kdvsiz] => 75.00
                    [Urun_adeti] => 3
                    [Urun_kuru] => TRY
                    [Urun_ds] => 100
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 4518
                    [Urun_kodu] => UK6FfrWzDPLE
                    [Urun_adi] => Besler Ton Balığı 2x160 Gr
                    [Urun_resim] => uploads/urunler_v/UK6FfrWzDPLE/bfeec-besler-ton-baligi-2x160-grqrgy6fl2hv.jpg
                    [Esas_tutar] => 10.80
                    [Esas_tutar_kdvsiz] => 10.00
                    [Kdv_tutar] => 0.80
                    [Kdv_tutar_adetli] => 2.40
                    [Adetli_tutar] => 32.40
                    [Adetli_tutar_kdvsiz] => 30.00
                    [Urun_adeti] => 3
                    [Urun_kuru] => TRY
                    [Urun_ds] => 32
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 4518
                    [Urun_kodu] => UK6FfrWzDPLE
                    [Urun_adi] => Besler Ton Balığı 2x160 Gr
                    [Urun_resim] => uploads/urunler_v/UK6FfrWzDPLE/bfeec-besler-ton-baligi-2x160-grqrgy6fl2hv.jpg
                    [Esas_tutar] => 10.80
                    [Esas_tutar_kdvsiz] => 10.00
                    [Kdv_tutar] => 0.80
                    [Kdv_tutar_adetli] => 2.40
                    [Adetli_tutar] => 32.40
                    [Adetli_tutar_kdvsiz] => 30.00
                    [Urun_adeti] => 3
                    [Urun_kuru] => TRY
                    [Urun_ds] => 32
                )


        )
)
```

Below, you can see my steps when pushing new array

```
$Urun = $SepetBilgisi->Urun;

        $MevcutUrunSayisi=count($Urun);
        $YeniUrun=[];
        foreach($Urun as $Key => $Value)
        {
            if($Value->Id== $UrunId){  // My target is $UrunId=4518 that means  $Urun[Urun][1] one
                unset($Urun[$Key]);

                if(count($Urun)< $MevcutUrunSayisi){

                    //Şimdi Yeni Array Buraya Ekleyelim

                    $YeniUrun[$Key]=[

                        "Id"=> $Value->Id,
                        "Urun_kodu" => $Value->Urun_kodu,
                        "Urun_resim" => $Value->Urun_resim,
                        "Esas_tutar" => $Value->Esas_tutar,
                        "Esas_tutar_kdvsiz" => $Value->Esas_tutar_kdvsiz,
                        "Kdv_tutar" => $Value->Kdv_tutar,
                        "Kdv_tutar_adetli" => $Value->Kdv_tutar_adetli,
                        "Adetli_tutar" => $Value->Adetli_tutar,
                        "Adetli_tutar_kdvsiz" => $Value->Adetli_tutar_kdvsiz,
                        "Urun_adeti" => $YeniAdet,
                        "Urun_kuru" => $Value->Urun_kuru,
                        "Urun_ds" => $Value->Urun_ds
                    ];

                    array_push($Urun , $YeniUrun);

                }else{
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }
```

Using 'array_push' only put new array end of main array as you know.

Comment: You do not what to push to the array, you want to replace the the key.

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace the key, not push to the end of the array:

```
    $Urun = $SepetBilgisi->Urun;

    $MevcutUrunSayisi=count($Urun);
    $YeniUrun=[];
    foreach($Urun as $Key => $Value)
    {
        if($Value->Id== $UrunId){  // My target is $UrunId=4518 that means  $Urun[Urun][1] one

            if(count($Urun)< $MevcutUrunSayisi){

                //Şimdi Yeni Array Buraya Ekleyelim

                $replace=[
                    "Id"=> $Value->Id,
                    "Urun_kodu" => $Value->Urun_kodu,
                    "Urun_resim" => $Value->Urun_resim,
                    "Esas_tutar" => $Value->Esas_tutar,
                    "Esas_tutar_kdvsiz" => $Value->Esas_tutar_kdvsiz,
                    "Kdv_tutar" => $Value->Kdv_tutar,
                    "Kdv_tutar_adetli" => $Value->Kdv_tutar_adetli,
                    "Adetli_tutar" => $Value->Adetli_tutar,
                    "Adetli_tutar_kdvsiz" => $Value->Adetli_tutar_kdvsiz,
                    "Urun_adeti" => $YeniAdet,
                    "Urun_kuru" => $Value->Urun_kuru,
                    "Urun_ds" => $Value->Urun_ds
                ];

                $Urun[$Key] = $replace;

            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```